# Why is subSet method specified in SortedSet Interface instead of Set?

Tags: java, set, treeset, sortedset

Why is `subSet` method specified in `SortedSet` Interface instead of Set unlike `subList` method of `List` interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `subSet` operation requires the underlying `Set` to have ordering. Otherwise there's no meaning to request all the elements from element X to element Y.

The base `Set` interface doesn't require ordering (for example, `HashSet`s are not ordered). Therefore it can't support this operation.

The `List` interface is ordered, so having `subList()` method there makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The elements in a Set are not ordered, so it would be undetermined, what elements a subset would contain.